# Delphi gives F2613 "Unit not found", but only for 64-bit build

Tags: delphi, 32bit-64bit, library-path

I have been developing my software with Delphi and use two 3rd party packages: TRichview and LMD ElPack. I have one unit in TRichview, and 3 units in LMD Elpack that I have added my own customizations to, so I keep my 4 customized versions of these units with in my directory with my project files.

Ever since I installed Delphi 10.4, and installed versions of TRichView and ElPack compatible with 10.4, I have been having a peculiar problem. The one customized unit in TRichView is giving me:

> [dcc64 Fatal Error] RVEdit.pas(1054): F2613 Unit 'RVERVData' not found

[image]

but it is only giving me that error when building to Windows 64-bit. When building to Windows 32-bit, it builds and runs without problem.

My Tools > Options > Language > Delphi > Library > Windows [32|64]-bit > LibraryPath both point correctly to the folders containing the .dcu and .res files for the 32-bit and 64-bit units.  The correct 32-bit RVERVData.dcu file is in the 32-bit folder, and the 64-bit RVERVData.dcu file is in the 64-bit folder.

The really strange thing is this:  If I rename both the .pas and .dcu files for the TRichView unit that I customized, then everything rebuilds fine in both 32-bit and 64-bit, so Delphi is obviously using the correct 64-bit library paths.

I know this was not a problem previously. In January 2020, I had no problems and successfully ran and compiled 64-bit. All I have done since then is install the Delphi 10.4 patches and the latest version of TRichview. I have upgraded to 10.4.1, but the problem still exists.

So why is this error occurring, but just in 64-bit builds (not 32-bit) and what can I do to get a 64-bit build working with my customized unit?

Comment: Try adding the unit in the project explicitly instead of using search paths. I always add all units in my project and never use search paths. This way I'm always sure about which units are used.

Comment: @fpiette - Thanks for the idea. But I already have my customized unit added to my project and I keep it in my project folder. The search paths are for the pre-compiled units of my 3rd party packages. I don't want those recompiled every build, which is what would happen if they were added to the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a strange one. I opened a case with Embarcadero and we now seem to have fixed it.

I uninstalled and reinstalled the TRichView package. The library path setup was different for their 32-bit and their 64-bit package. Once I cleaned this up, both 32-bit and 64-started to build properly and I don’t get the error for this case any more.

I don't know what specifically caused this, but it must have been related in some way to some improper library paths, even though I checked those many times during my attempts to find and fix the problem.